# Java HtmlUnit Memory Leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, htmlunit

I got the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    navigate(list.get(i));
}
```

And for the navigate method:

```
HtmlTextInput txtInput = page.getElementByName("input");
txtInput.setValueAttribute("random");


HtmlSubmitInput btnNext = page.getHtmlElementById("btn_next");
page = btnNext.click();


HtmlSubmitInput btnConfirm = page.getElementByName("submit");
page = btnConfirm.click();


System.out.println("before: " + webClient.getWebWindows().size());
page.cleanUp();
page.deregisterFramesIfNeeded(); 
System.out.println("after: " + webClient.getWebWindows().size());

return true;
```

`HtmlPage` and `WebClient` have been declared globally.

To put it in perspective, I fill in a form, press OK, press Confirm and I got redirected to my initial page so I repeat the process. The problem is that my application is eating up all the memory. And later on this will throw a heap exception.

If I count the web windows I see that number growing and never decreasing. A lot of other topic about this memory leak suggests that I have to call the `.CloseAllWindows()` method but this feature has been removed.

Currently I am using HtmlUnit 2.25.

Did I make a mistake while redirecting so that older windows stay in the background?

**UPDATED VERSION:**

Creation of a new WebClient method:

```
private WebClient createNewWebClient(){
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45);

        // no exceptions
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        // other settings 
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(300000);

        // enable sessions
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

        // Set session if any
        if (cookieManager == null){
            cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        } else {
            webClient.setCookieManager(cookieManager);
        }
        return webClient;
    }
```

Loop stayed the same. Navigate method:

```
     try (WebClient webClient = createNewWebClient()) {
                HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("URL");
                HtmlTextInput txtInput = page.getElementByName("input");
                txtInput.setValueAttribute("random");


                HtmlSubmitInput btnNext = page.getHtmlElementById("btn_next");
                page = btnNext.click();


                HtmlSubmitInput btnConfirm = page.getElementByName("submit");
                page = btnConfirm.click();

             ...
       }
```

Memory is still increasing with every method call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `webClient.close()`, or simply put it in `try-with-resources`, for example:

```
try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080";
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);

    // do something
}
```

**Update :**

You can store the `CookieManager` of `webClient.getCookieManager()` and use it for other `WebClient`s.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Doing this will close my session correct? Because I want to keep navigating within one session. This because I have to login before reaching this inital page and I do not want to keep logging in for every send request.

Comment: Yes, this will close the session.  You can cache WebClient, but make sure you close it and open a new one every e.g. 100 request

Comment: The problem is that I get a heap exception after 5 navigate calls because then I got more than 100+ web windows open. Is it possible to reduce this number? Or is it possible to only save the session and not the web windows?

Comment: Ok thank you! I changed my code and per request I create a new WebClient and pass the session to this instance. Now I see that my memory is going up at a much slower rate and I also see it decreasing so the memory leak has been fixed for 95%. The only issue I still have is that for every request, the peak memory goes up by a few extra MB so I guess it will crash again after a longer periode of time. Is there something I can do to stabilize the memory usage? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see that my memory is going up every time I call the webClient.getPage(url) in my loop.

Comment: Yes after 3 minutes my memory passes 1000 MB and still increasing.

Comment: Please update your question, with full complete case.

Comment: The URL is needed for others to exactly replicate the issue

Comment: I cannot provide the url because it is an internal site. But this site consists of an login form which is handled before my loop. When logging in, I keep submitting another form which is increasing my memory a lot.

Comment: I have downgraded to htmlUnit 2.20 and my leak seems to be gone. However, it handles the javascript on my pages not how I want to.

Comment: Since private URL is used, you need to profile the application and provide minimal case.

Comment: Hi @Schippert, i'm also facing the memory issue. But which tool are you using to monitory the memory leaks. Because i want make use of it to identify how much memory my application used it. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

maimArt is right, in some cases the page.cleanUp(); was not completely processed from webClient.close();. This is fixed now and will be part of the upcoming 2.44 release.

In cases like this it will be great if you report the issues to the GitHub project, otherwise we have no chance to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem. After many hours of debugging and memory analysis, i found out that it´s not enough to just close the webclient. You also need to cleanup the loaded page to release all nested references.

I wrapped the WebClient in another Closable class to do this.

So in your case this sould fix your memory leak:

```
WebClient webclient = null;
HtmlPage page = hull;
try {
            webClient = createNewWebClient()
            page = webClient.getPage("URL");
            HtmlTextInput txtInput = page.getElementByName("input");
            txtInput.setValueAttribute("random");


            HtmlSubmitInput btnNext = page.getHtmlElementById("btn_next");
            page = btnNext.click();


            HtmlSubmitInput btnConfirm = page.getElementByName("submit");
            page = btnConfirm.click();

         ...
   } finally {
            page.cleanUp();
            webClient.close();
   }
```